# Determine the frequency $\omega$ from an initial value problem $\frac{2y(t)}{z(\omega)}=-0.03y'(t)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble finding y(t) hence $\omega$ in this question.

$$ \frac{2y(t)}{0.46+81.54j \omega+\dfrac{(0.516+0.81j\omega)81.54j\omega}{0.516+0.81j\omega+81.54j\omega}} = -(30\times 10^{-3}) y'(t) $$

where $ y(0)=30 $ and $ y'(0) = 0 $

$\omega$ represents $2\pi f$ since this equation is to be solved to find the frequency.

it doesn't work applying $y(t) = C_1 e^{-\lambda t}$ because I think the equation of $y(t)$ has to include $\omega$ in it somewhere, probably in a sine or cosine. I kinda sense that y(t) must be something like $e^{-\lambda t}\cos(\omega t)$ but not it because I tried it and it doesn't work either.

How would I solve this kind of differential equations?

Comment: Am I missing something or is this just $y(t) = a\cdot y'(t)$ for $a=\frac{-30\cdot 10^{-3}}{z(\omega)}$?

Comment: it is like $2*y(t) = a*y'(t)$ for $a = -30\times 10^{-3} \times z(ω)$ but the thing is y(t) must be some equation that has ω in it as a frequency element.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using "$*$" and "$\times$"? This is all just multiplication of complex numbers, right? Furthermore, $\omega$ is just a constant, of course it will appear in the solution. This is just an equation of the type $y(t) = \text{some constant}\cdot y'(t)$ and can be solved easily as $y(t) = C\cdot e^{\text{some constant}\cdot t}$. Please edit your question to provide more context or details if this is not the case.

Comment: In my first comment I wanted to write "$a=-30\cdot 10^{-3}\cdot z(\omega)$", sorry.

Comment: only multiplication I didn't know if I should write $30*10^{-3}$ or $30\times 10^{-3}$ but I meant 0.03. In this problem the issue is that, yes, ω is a constant but we don't know what constant it is and ω is the mean question here. We want to find the frequency in the problem ω represents $2\pi f$ where $f$ is the frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me rewrite your differential equation as
$$
y(t) = \underbrace{-\frac{3}{200}\left(0.46+81.54jω+\frac{(0.516+0.81jω)81.54jω}{0.516+0.81jω+81.54jω}\right)}_{a}\cdot y'(t).
$$
As an equation of the type $y(t)=a\cdot y'(t)$, the solutions are exactly the functions
$$
y(t) = C\cdot e^{at}
$$
for some constant $C$. Hence in your case you get
$$
y(t) = C\cdot e^{-\frac{3}{200}\left(0.46+81.54jω+\frac{(0.516+0.81jω)81.54jω}{0.516+0.81jω+81.54jω}\right) t}.
$$

Now $y(0)=30$ tells you that $C=30$ and then $y'(0)=0$ gives
$$
y'(0) = Ca = -\frac{90}{200}\left(0.46+81.54jω+\frac{(0.516+0.81jω)81.54jω}{0.516+0.81jω+81.54jω}\right) =0.
$$
You can solve this for $\omega$.

Comment: doesn't this say that $y(t)$ is constant?

Comment: No, it is exponential in $t$.

Comment: $y'(0) = 0$ implies $a=0$...

Comment: You're right, I guess it is up to @Alper91 to decide if that is plausible in his context.

Comment: @Dylan weirdest thing is $ω = 2\pi f$ and f has two imaginal solutions and I don't know what it means and imaginal frequency is. I'm stunned.

Comment: @Alper91 is $\omega$ a function of $t$? I think we're not getting the full picture here.